# Add Network Service to Event Log Readers on Domain Controller server

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dc

I need to add a Network Service account to the Event Log Readers group which is part of Builtin groups on the Active Directory DC server using PowerShell script.

I am using the ActiveDirectory module but once I am running:
$user = "NETWORK SERVICE"
$group = "Event Log Readers"
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group -Member $user -Verbose

I am receiving an error stating:
Add-ADGroupMember: Cannot find an object with Identity: "NETWORK SERVICE" under: 'DC=xxx,DC=inc'

Note that I can go to the AD GUI and add this user under the group mentioned.

Your help is highly appreciated.

I am expecting to be able to add this user to the group using a PowerShell script

Comment: Why would you do this? The local computer already has access or you can just add the machine account.

Comment: I didn't get your question. I need it for my WEF configuration automation

Comment: Just add the machine account then: `computername$`

Comment: can you post an example please? if my post isn't clear I am ready for any clarification

Comment: See: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4efdd9ac-6b27-411e-b55c-887a53d7e076/adding-networkservice-account-to-terminal-server-license-servers-group?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Awesome, it worked. how can I add your comment as answer to my question? thanks

Comment: @Scepticalist how can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 2008 and later, the local Network Service runs under the AD Account of the computer and therefore you should only need to add the computer account

e.g. mydomain\mycomputername$